# How to access "remote desktop" folder from my local PC?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

When I connect to a remote computer using Windows Remote Desktop Connection, how can I access files on that remote desktop from my local Windows Explorer? I'm looking for the opposite of what you can configure in Remote Desktop Connection > Options > Local Resources > More.

Comment: Use the option you mentioned and, in the remote desktop, copy the files to your local drive.

Comment: I need to work with that remote file in a local application so I need that remote file visible locally in some kind of "shared folder".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think RDP supports such a feature. What would I do?

I would set up an FTP server and connect to it, then you wouldn't need to even RDP.

Better yet, I'd set up an SSH server:
http://lifehacker.com/#!205090/geek-to-live--set-up-a-personal-home-ssh-server

Then, I'd get dokan sshfs 
http://dokan-dev.net/en/download/

This way, the remote computer's drive would be mapped and ready to work with on my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, Windows 10 and 11 age, the best solution I have found is to not look for this feature inside RDP because it probably does not exist. If your local and remote desktops are on the same local network, use the old *File Explorer file sharing* feature instead.

There are different ways to share, and this is what I prefer.

1. Go to the Remote Desktop and set a Windows account password if you haven't one. Call this Remote Desktop Windows account RDWA.
2. right-click on the folder to share and select *Give access to* --> *Specific people...* --> choose RDWA --> *Share*
3. go back to your local Desktop, open File Explorer and type in the address bar \\YOUR-REMOTE-DESKTOP-NAME --> type in RDWA Username and Password.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. Communication can be two way:

http://help.npserv.org/wiki/index.php/Transferring_files_between_the_server_and_your_local_computer

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @Damien please dont leave link witch will become non-existing and therefore no one will know why you posted link. Post answer if you have some

Comment: That link is dead